# LibGDX: how to save a large amount of data?

Tags: sql, json, database, csv, libgdx

I am developing an application using LibGDX.

I would like to save a lot of sentences, each one with an index and the date when it was created.

The user should be able to find or select a specific sentence.

There should be sentences that are already created in the application (like in the assets folder) and the user should also be able to create his own sentences and to save them.

I am new to this topic and I dont know how to realize this idea.
I found some things during my research but I am confused because there is much information and I do not know which one I need.

Should I use JSON files, csv files, a SQL database, or something else?
And when, then how to do it with LibGDX?

I would be happy if you could give me some information on this topic or advice!

Comment: Be sure to provide an example what you have tried or at least what you have looked at doing via research.

Comment: JSON would be easiest because LibGDX has built-in support for it and you could test it in desktop builds. SQLite would be better if your number of sentences was enormous, such that you don't want to load the whole set to memory. But it would be harder to implement because you'd need to write some interfaces and Android-specific code.

Comment: @JohnK I have not tried anything so far because I was not sure what to start with. But I have looked at things I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Would it be better to save all of the sentences in a single JSON file (about 1000 sentences), or to separate them somehow?

Comment: you could use Sqlite to do that, very fast, very reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences is the way to go unless you are talking about thousands of user sentences. It also depends on the scalablity, if you just want to add strings this does the job. If you need to lookup specific string you probably need to load them all. Preferences are stored in local so each module has easy access to it by the Gdx interface. This is how you use `Preferences`

```
    Preferences preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences("filename");       
    preferences.putString(Key<String>, Value);
    preferences.flush();
```

Now to be able to keep adding strings you need to increment the key each time you put a string in the preferences. You could do this in preferences as well.

```
    int stringCount = preferences.getInteger("string_count"); // Get current string count
    preferences.putInteger("string_counr", stringCount++); // Increment stringCount and put it back in preferences
    preferences.putString("userstring_" + stringCount, someString); // Create string using incremented stringCount.
    preferences.flush(); //Store data
```

You can access the strings by using the string count. Or you can load them all on runtime. Depending on your needs you could also store the exact string as the key, but you will have a hard time retrieving them if you don't know the string.

```
    int stringCount = preferences.getInteger("string_count");
    List<String> userStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= stringCount; i++)
    {
        userStrings.add(preferences.getString("userstring_" + stringCount);
    }
```

The strings are stored on windows in `users/username/.prefs/filename`

I have stored a couple of hundred fields into preferences without any issues. It's not the fastest on the `flush()` but you can probably store all the sentences and batch flush them. If your needs are not too demanding preferences are easy to do. If you look for a lot more scalable option then you should go with JSON, XML, a scripting language or perhaps write your own reader/writer for it. A database would be overkill unless you want to link users and other data to these sentences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a question: I'd like, for example, to get all the sentences sorted by date, or by length, or to get only the favorite-sentences etc. Do you think it would be better to use a database for that?

Comment: Since you increment each new sentence its already sorted by time. You can store dates to. When you store them in a data structure you can sort on length, alpha or whatever. If you really need a date you can always link a date entry in the prefs with that increment count as a link between date and sentence. However, if you want to create a lot of these links eventually a database will be more beneficial.

Comment: @red1575, you're welcome. What I meant with "a lot of these links" is a lot of different type of data links, not a lot of `string`->`date` links. Essentially a database is perfect for these solutions but if you just want to store a date and perhaps a username allongside that string, preferences is still good for that and easiest to implement. When you want to link a lot of things to these sentences and other data entities then you should look into a DB. Like `sentence` links to `date` & `user`. `user` links to `login info` & `other gameplay data`. etc..